# how to make Hp wireless headset h8000 work in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, wireless

I am Manoj , I am using ubuntu 12.04 .

I am not able to connect my hp headset to ubuntu .

Please provide a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

look you have to connect the headset , then go to system settings ,click in SOUND and there you will find the option "output" that said  "play sound through" and there it have to be the headset,so you choose it and there you go 
And for go back for the normal audio (speakers) you just select it in the same place 
good luck¡